# seleniumで要素取得したいが，２つ同名のものがあるため，後者を選択できない

Tags: selenium

```html
<a href="URL" target="_blank" class="button button-color-2">新規会員登録</a>
<a class="button">ログイン</a>
```

ここで，

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.button').click()
```

Comment: これが応用できるのでは？ [要素を複数指定する](https://www.mittsu-kosen.com/%E3%80%90pythonxselenium%E3%80%91web%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AC%E3%82%A4%E3%83%94%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E3%81%A7%E3%82%88%E3%81%8F%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%86%E6%93%8D%E4%BD%9C%E3%83%A1%E3%82%BD%E3%83%83/#i-12)

Answer (score 1):

コメントに紹介した`要素を複数指定する`とか、他にも`Pythonでスクレイピング（2）seleniumの使い方`に以下のような説明があります。

[要素を複数指定する](https://www.mittsu-kosen.com/%E3%80%90pythonxselenium%E3%80%91web%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AC%E3%82%A4%E3%83%94%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E3%81%A7%E3%82%88%E3%81%8F%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%86%E6%93%8D%E4%BD%9C%E3%83%A1%E3%82%BD%E3%83%83/#i-12)

> **要素を複数指定する**
> 指定された要素を複数個取得するコマンドです。
> 取得した値はリスト形式で返されます。
> 基本的には上で紹介したコマンドを「element」→「elements」に変えるだけです。
>
> cssセレクタで指定する
>
> ```
> driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("CSS selector")
> ```

[Pythonでスクレイピング（2）seleniumの使い方](https://itstudio.co/2018/12/10/8651/)

> **複数の要素を取得**
> タグ名やクラス名で要素を指定すると複数の要素を取ることができます。
> その時は、「find_element」部分を「find_elements」として配列で取得したい要素のインデックスを指定します。
>
> ```
> elem2 = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('post-content')
> elem2[1].text
> ```

上記を応用すれば例えば以下のように出来るのでは？

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.button')[1].click()
```

---

他には解決済にはなっていませんが、`+1`の回答のあるこの記事とか。

[python selenium classの指定方法について](https://teratail.com/questions/108682)

> python　seleniumを使ってclassを指定するときに以下のようなclassが複数あるとします。
>
> ```
> <div class="hoge"></div>
> <div class="hoge"></div>
> <div class="hoge"></div>
> ```
>
> 例えばこのclassから二つ目のclassをクリックしたいという場合の指定の方法を教えていただけないでしょうか？
>
> こんな感じでしょうか？
>
> ```
> driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".hoge:nth-of-type(2)").click()
> ```

---

試してみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます．driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.button')[1].click()　で解決しました．もう一つの方法も参考にさせていただきます．